# How can I skip a call to write! when pattern matching for fmt::Display?

Tags: enums, rust, pattern-matching

Consider the following enum:

```
enum SomeEnum { A, B, C }
```

And the following `fmt::Display` implementation:

```
impl fmt::Display for SomeEnum {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        use SomeEnum::*;

        match *self {
            A => write!(f, "A"),
            B => write!(f, "B"),
            // I'm not interested in calling write! for C
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to skip the `write!` function call for one particular enum value (in this case `C`) when pattern matching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the return type of `fmt` is `fmt::Result`, you just need to supply an empty `Ok(())` value in order for all the possible return values of `match` have the same type (and the code to compile):

```
impl fmt::Display for SomeEnum {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        use SomeEnum::*;

        match *self {
            A => write!(f, "A"),
            B => write!(f, "B"),
            C => Ok(()),
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to use `C => unreachable!()`, but this is a good idea only if you are certain that value will never need to be `Display`ed (otherwise it would cause a panic).

Comment: If you don't care of many other value you can do `_ => Ok(())`